# Ask for Permission for Remote Notifications in iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I'm adding remote notifications with `ArenaDeamons`, but I'm getting an error (`MY APP KEY` is my private key):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    BDArenaConnector.initializeWithAppKey("MY APP KEY", runInSandboxEnvironment: true)
    BDArenaConnector.getInstance().requestAuth()
    // register for remote notifications
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings.settingsForTypes((UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge), categories: nil))
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    BDArenaConnector.getInstance().pushConnector.feedbackServiceDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions(launchOptions)
    return true

UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    return true
}
```

Error1: `use of unresolved identifier 'UIUserNotificationTypeBadge'`
Error2: `use of unresolved identifier 'UIUserNotificationTypeSound'`
Error3: `use of unresolved identifier 'UIUserNotificationTypeAlert'`

I also have some errors here:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    print("UIApplication : didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError : \(error.localizedDescription)")
    var alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "did Fail To Register For Remote Notifications", message: error.localizedDescription(), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleAlert)
    var okAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction.actionWithTitle("Ok!", style: UIAlertActionStyleDefault, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in
    })
    alert.addAction(okAction)
    self.window!.rootViewController!.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Error1: `use of unresolved identifier 'UIalertcontrollerstylealert'`
Error2: `use of unresolved identifier 'UIalertactionstyledefault'`

How Can I fix it? The app is in Swift 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ios 8 and above, you can use registerUserNotificationSettings,
try this code, i have not tested it but, it will help you for sure.

```
let types = UIUserNotificationType.Badge.union(UIUserNotificationType.Alert).union(UIUserNotificationType.Sound)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil))
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Fix for Error 3

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    print("UIApplication : didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError : \(error.localizedDescription)")
    let alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "did Fail To Register For Remote Notifications", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let okAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in
    })
    alert.addAction(okAction)
    self.window!.rootViewController!.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `UIAlertActionStyle.Default` and `UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in part. Now I have only 2 errors. Thanks Prabhu.Somasundaram.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    print("UIApplication : didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError : \(error.localizedDescription)")
    let alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "did Fail To Register For Remote Notifications", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let okAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in
    })
    alert.addAction(okAction)
    self.window!.rootViewController!.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Error 1: invalid use of '()' to call a value of non-function Type 'String'

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    BDArenaConnector.getInstance().pushConnector.feedbackServiceDidReceiveRemoteNotification(userInfo)
    // handle push
    BDArenaConnector.getInstance().pushConnector.handlePush(userInfo, withPresentingController: self.window!.rootViewController, withActionButtonHandler: {

        }, withCancelButtonHandler: {

    })
}
```

Error 2: Value of optional type 'UIWindow' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

How Can I fix?